# php foreach() error message

Tags: php, html

I'm creating a mobile website that takes feeds from a rss link and displays it as list..

here is my code

```
  <div data-role="content"> 
  <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="c" data-dividertheme="a" data-counttheme="a">
  <?php            
      foreach($feed->query->results->item as $item) {       
  ?>
      <li>
         <a href="article.php?notices=<?php echo $siteName;?>&origLink=<?php echo urlencode($item->guid->content);?>">
             <?php echo $item->title; ?>
         </a>
      </li>
  <?php  } ?>
  </ul>
</div>
```

but this is showing an error on line 12! which is below foreach($feed->query->results->item as $item)

[image]

**EDIT:**
Thanks everyone for your help. The rss link had slow response time so the YQL was timing out.. but now it's working..

Comment: check whether $feed->query->results->item is array, print array using print_r($feed->query->results->item)

Comment: Is `$feed->query->results->item` an array of items?

Comment: can u add the feed as well? You might be parsing it wrong..

Comment: paste output of print_r($feed->query->results->item).

Comment: I can't post it because YQL is timing out.

Answer (score 1):

Try to check for `is_array` like

```
if( is_array($feed->query->results->item) ) {
    foreach($feed->query->results->item as $item) {
          //The run the foreach loop
    } 
}
```

An if it is not an array then print the single result.Even we need to check whether they are getting results or not.

Comment: I don't think the OP means that it can sometimes be an array and sometimes an object... Probably just a mistake somewhere in the code, so don't you think this condition isn't suppose to be there on run?

Comment: Probably the error message he will get only when whether it is not an array or may be it is empty

Answer (score 1):

This is just guesswork but I think `$feed->query->results->item` is *not* an array. What you meant was `$feed->query->results` perhaps?

```
foreach ($feed->query->results as $item) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think **$feed->query->results->item** this is empty. So it would be great if You provide the output of **$feed**.

then it will be easier to give You the exact result.

Answer (score 0):

$feed->query->results->item is not an array ... or nothing is returning from the DB .. try to var_dump($feed->query->results->item) before the foreach and check if you are looping on the right value